# Groupby functions in Pandas to combine string values

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pivot-table

My df is in the following Format:

[image]

When i do a **df.groupby('Tool').sum()** i get the following:

[image]

The expected output is the following:

[image]

Please guide me in achieving the desired output.

Comment: 1. Do not post images of the dataframe but a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 2. What have you tried until now (except the `groupby.sum()` line)? Did you move past that?

Comment: Apologies for posting dataframe as image. Will avoid doing it next time onwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with convert values to `set`s and then join by `/`:

```
df.groupby('Tool').agg(lambda x: '/'.join(set(x)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#You can also use-
df.groupby('Tool').agg(min("Cost Center") as "Cost Center",min("Nature") as "Nature").show
```